# How to get the Updated Size of Structure?Size of the Structure not getting Updated When I add values to dynamic array Fields

Tags: c#, .net, struct, structure

This is related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437731/while-creating-a-array-inside-a-structure-does-that-structure-contain-directly), and thought will make this as a sparate question as it will make more sense.

I have created my Struct as :

```
public struct Smb_Parameters
        {
            public byte WordCount;
            public ushort[] Words;
        }
```

Without Assigning any Values when I try to get the size of the Struct it returns 4-Bytes:

```
Smb_Parameters smbParameter = new Smb_Parameters();
int len1 = Marshal.SizeOf(smbParameter );
            MessageBox.Show(len1.ToString());
```

But When I assign the Values to structure fields :

```
 Smb_Parameters smbParameter = new Smb_Parameters();
 string myString= "String  ll be converted to byte";
 smbParameter.WordCount=0x00;
 smbParameter .Words=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString);
 int len1 = Marshal.SizeOf(smbParameter );
 MessageBox.Show(len1.ToString());
```

Still now It shows the Length as 4-Bytes but I need the updated size.

Comment: Why are you setting the Wordcount to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to get the size as if it was an *unmanaged* type, you'd need to supply some information about its fields (e.g., the length of the array).  Without it, the array length would not be taken into account.

e.g.,

```
public struct Smb_Parameters1
{
    public byte WordCount; //1 byte
    public ushort[] Words; //4 bytes (a "pointer")
}
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Smb_Parameters1)); //8 (with padding)
//I don't see how you get 4 unless you are on a 16-bit system maybe

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Smb_Parameters2
{
    public byte WordCount; //1 byte
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)]
    public ushort[] Words; //20 bytes (2 * 10 bytes)
}
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Smb_Parameters2)); //22 (with padding)
```

Note that these are sizes are fixed (as if it was declared in a C/C++ program).  The size reported by `SizeOf()` will only use these and not take into account what size array you store in `Words`.

```
Smb_Parameters1 s1 = new Smb_Parameters1() { Words = new ushort[] { 0, 1, 2 } };
Smb_Parameters2 s2 = new Smb_Parameters2() { Words = new ushort[] { 0, 1, 2 } };
Marshal.SizeOf(s1); //8 bytes
Marshal.SizeOf(s2); //22 bytes
```

Comment: May be I am getting 4 because I am using Marshal.SizeOf(Smb_Parameters1); not Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Smb_Parameters1)); I am quite sure though it is not a 16-bit System

Answer (score 1):

The `Words` field is an array, and arrays are reference types. The structure doesn't actually contains the array items, it only contains a reference to the array, which is stored somewhere else (typically on the heap). So `SizeOf` always returns the same size, since the size of a reference doesn't depend on the size of the object pointed by that reference.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way we can get the actual size of the strucure.

Comment: The actual size of the structure is exactly what is returned by Marshal.SizeOf... it's just that the array items are NOT part of the structure

Answer (score 0):

`Marshal.SizeOf()` returns a fixed size of an class/struct. The length does never depend on the contents of your object passed.

You could calculate the size with `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte))+Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ushort))*yourarraylength`

Another way would be to use  the `BinaryFormatter` class to serialize your struct into binary form. It returns you a byte array. If you take the length of it you know its serialized size. Note that the result of BinaryFormatter cannot not be easily read by a non-.net language since its format is native to .net only.